# Python pytz, zoneinfo and daylight savings time

Tags: python, datetime, dst, pytz, zoneinfo

I am currently attempting to migrate a code base from using `pytz` to using Python's `zoneinfo` library. I've run into an issue with how `zoneinfo` handles daylight saving time transitions when compared to how `pytz` handles them.

Suppose I have a naive `datetime` object:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> start = datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 30, 23, 0)
```

The approach used for making this object timezone-aware using `pytz` was to use `localize`, as follows:

```
>>> local_timezone = pytz.timezone('Europe/Copenhagen')
>>> start_cet = local_timezone.localize(start)
>>> start_cet
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 30, 23, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Copenhagen' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

Notice that `start_cet` is very close to the end of CEST 2021. If I add, say, 5 hours onto this time, I get the following:

```
>>> end = start_cet + datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
>>> end
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 31, 4, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Copenhagen' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
```

Now, in reality, adding 5 hours on to `start_cet` should in fact land us on 3:00 on 2021/10/31, since leaving DST takes us back one hour, moving from CEST to CET. We can get the correct value by applying `astimezone` with our `pytz` timezone:

```
>>> end.astimezone(local_timezone)
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 31, 3, 0, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Copenhagen' CET+1:00:00 STD>)
```

**Question: What is the equivalent method of finding the actual time when moving through DST when using `zoneinfo`?**

Here's what I've tried. `zoneinfo` has no `localize` method, instead we are recommended to simply use `replace`:

```
>>> local_timezone = zoneinfo.ZoneInfo('Europe/Copenhagen')
>>> start_cet = start.replace(tzinfo=local_timezone)
>>> start_cet
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 30, 23, 0, tzinfo=backports.zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Copenhagen'))
>>> start_cet.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(seconds=7200)
```

`zoneinfo` has the benefit over `pytz` that adding a `timedelta` will successfully transition us into the correct timezone (as can be seen by the `utcoffset` result:

```
>>> end = start_cet + datetime.timedelta(hours=5)
>>> end
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 31, 4, 0, tzinfo=backports.zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Copenhagen'))
>>> end.utcoffset()
datetime.timedelta(seconds=3600)
```

Despite this, with `zoneinfo` timezones there seems to be no way to get what the *actual time* would have been when adding 5 hours onto `start_cet`. As shown above, with `pytz` I can use `astimezone`, but with `zoneinfo`, this does not change anything:

```
>>> end.astimezone(tz=local_timezone)
datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 31, 4, 0, tzinfo=backports.zoneinfo.ZoneInfo(key='Europe/Copenhagen'))
```

Comment: Using "CET" rather wrong. In European locations, CET is used in winter, and CEST in summer. You're supposed to use a concrete location-based timezone like `Europe/Berlin`, which will make the library transition correctly between CET and CEST. Since different countries (may) transition at different times, there's no "end of CET" per se.

Comment: You're correct I was using 'CET' too generally. I'll update the question to reflect that. The same problem persists when I use a concrete timezone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to @deceze's comment (CET specifies a UTC offset, not a time zone), note that timedelta arithmetic in Python is ***[wall time arithmetic](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/02/aware-datetime-arithmetic.html)***.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

eu_berlin_tz = ZoneInfo("Europe/Berlin")

start = datetime(2021, 10, 30, 23, 0, tzinfo=eu_berlin_tz)

dur = timedelta(hours=5)

print(start)
# 2021-10-30 23:00:00+02:00 => CEST

print(start + dur)
# 2021-10-31 04:00:00+01:00 => CET
```

2021-10-30T23:00:00+02:00 to 2021-10-31T04:00:00+01:00 is 5 hours on a wall clock, although a duration of 6 hours passed in reality due to DST becoming inactive.

If you add the duration in UTC and then convert back to the specified time zone, the result is more what you expect IIUC:

```py
def aware_add(dt, duration):
    return (dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("UTC")) + duration).astimezone(dt.tzinfo)

print(aware_add(start, dur))
# 2021-10-31 03:00:00+01:00
```

2021-10-30T23:00:00+02:00 to 2021-10-31T03:00:00+01:00 is 4 hours on the wall clock but 5 hours in reality.